# Adding items to a LIST<> of objects results in duplicate Objects when using a NEW in a Loop

Tags: c#, list, loops

```
List<BillOfLading> bolList = new List<BillOfLading>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BillOfLading newBol = new BillOfLading("AXSY1414114");
    bolList.Add(newBol);

    newBol.BillOfLadingNumber = "CRXY99991231";
    bolList.Add(newBol);
}
```

I was expecting that `bolList` would container two different objects or values, but it appears that this simple code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Resulting Immediates:

```
bolList

Count = 2
    [0]: {kTracker.BillOfLading}
    [1]: {kTracker.BillOfLading}
bolList[0]
{kTracker.BillOfLading}
    _billOfLadingNumber: "CRXY99991231"
    BillOfLadingNumber: "CRXY99991231"
bolList[1]
{kTracker.BillOfLading}
    _billOfLadingNumber: "CRXY99991231"
    BillOfLadingNumber: "CRXY99991231"
```

Comment: It appears to me that the code you wrote matches the output your getting. What is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 11):

You've only created one object, and added it twice. The fact that you modified that object between the first and second add is irrelevant; the list contains a reference to the object you added, so later changes to it will apply.

You need to replace `newBol.BillOfLadingNumber = "..";` with `newBol = new BillOfLading("..");`

Comment: I see... That's the key... It contains a Reference to the object I added... hmm.... Is there a way to do this without having to do newBol1, newbol2, etc.  (I don't know how many will be added). ? Any ideas ?

Comment: @Havingfun: You can reuse the same *variable* - but you need to assign a new *value* to the variable.

Comment: Well, you can do `bolList.Add(new BillOfLading('xx'));` as many times you as you like.

Comment: This is actually one of those most difficult things to keep track of when you're learning object-oriented programming; being aware of what objects you're creating, and what you're doing with them. There's a LOT of times where you'll create an object almost as a side effect of whatever you're trying to do, and not even notice that it exists; I've lost count of the number of times I've ended up with two or more separated objects representing the same thing, where I should only have one, or been modifying a single object where I should have been creating a new one each time.

Comment: @Havingfun you should mark this question as solved :-)

Answer (score 7):

Flynn1179's answer is correct, but to answer your comment - you don't need a different variable for each object. You can do:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BillOfLading newBol = new BillOfLading("AXSY1414114");
    bolList.Add(newBol);

    newBol = new BillOfLading("CRXY99991231");
    bolList.Add(newBol);
}
```

The important thing to understand is that you're not adding the *variable* to the list, nor are you adding the *object* to the list... you're adding the *current value of the variable* to the list. That current value is a reference to an instance of `BillOfLading`. In the above code, the list ends up with references to two different objects.